# What's the minimal distance between two curves?

Tags: calculus, optimization

What is the minimal distance between curves? I've tried to use the distance formula, but it did not work that well.

Given two curves:

[curve1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDU6V.png)
[curve2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH5Nf.png)
I got the following formula to minimalize.

[distance_formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eWqU.png)

How can I do this? Also, how can you calculate the minimal distance between two implicit defined curves. For example:
[implicit1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CniyO.png)
and
[implicit2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4JtM.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question. However, please don't post links to images of functions. Instead, mark up using MathJax. See:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Try to find one point on each curve such that the normals at those points coincide

Comment: Of possible use is [Distance Between Curves in First-Semester Calculus](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/19595/745), although the discussion there is mostly on how to teach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general case can be hard to digest. Even those basic distance problems require the help of numeric processes to obtain the results. An amiable case is when the functions involved are analytic. In this case we can use the Lagrange Multipliers formulation which can discover the curve points under a common normal. In this case given

$$
\cases{f_1(x,y) = 0\\
f_2(x,y) = 0}
$$

according to the Lagrange multipliers

$$
L(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = (x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+\lambda_1f_1(x_1,y_1)+\lambda_2(x_2,y_2)
$$

the minimum distance is found between the solutions for the lagrangian stationary points which are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 =\cases{
2(x_1-x_2)+\lambda_1 {f_1(x_1,y_1)}_{x_1}=0\\
-2(x_1-x_2) + \lambda_2 {f_2(x_2,y_2)}_{x_2}=0\\
2(y_1-y_2)+\lambda_1 {f_1(x_1,y_1)}_{y_1}=0\\
-2(y_1-y_2) + \lambda_2 {f_2(x_2,y_2)}_{y_2}=0\\
f_1(x_1,y_1) = 0\\
f_2(x_2,y_2) = 0
}
$$

Six nonlinear equations to six unknowns.

Follows a MATHEMATICA scrip to perform those calculations for the two asked cases.

```
f1[x_, y_] := y - x^2 - 1
f2[x_, y_] := y - Sin[x]
f1[x_, y_] := x^2 + 4 y^2 - 1
f2[x_, y_] := 13 x^2 + 10 x y + 13 y^2 - 36
d = (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2;
L = d + l1 f1[x1, y1] + l2 f2[x2, y2];
grad = Grad[L, {x1, x2, y1, y2, l1, l2}]
sol = NMinimize[grad.grad, {x1, x2, y1, y2, l1, l2}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

gr1 = ContourPlot[{f1[x, y] == 0, f2[x, y] == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
pts = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. sol[[2]];
grp1 = Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts[[1]]]}];
grp2 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts[[2]]]}];
grs12 = ParametricPlot[t pts[[1]] + (1 - t) pts[[2]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed}];
Show[gr1, grp1, grp2, grs12]
```

[image]
[image]

NOTE

Here the minimization process is used as an indirect way to solve the nonlinear system.